# Project Management Plugin for SharePoint

Tags: office-365, project-templates

What plug-ins/applications would you suggest for use with SharePoint? We have looked at BrightWork but are looking for some alternatives as well specifically ones that would be compatible with Office 365 + SharePoint Online. Looking for something that provides customizable templates and dashboard reporting.